# Create & Copy Access tables to SQL via SSIS? SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, upsizing

I am trying come up with a way to pull the tables out of an Access database, automate the creation of those same tables in a SQL 2008 DB, and move the data to the new tables. This process will happen on a regular basis and there may be different tables each time.

I would like to do this totally in SSIS.

C# SQL CLR objects are an option.

The main issue I have been running into is how to get the Access table's schema and then convert that to a SQL script that I can run via SSIS.

Any ideas?

TIA
J

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use MS Access's export menu item, or script it in VBA using "DoCmd.TransferDatabase transfertype"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSIS cannot adapt to new tables at runtime.  (You can change connections, move a source to a table with a different name, but the same schema)  So, it's not really easy to do what I think you are saying: Upsize an arbitrary set of tables in an Access DB to SQL (mirroring their structure and data, naming, etc), so that I can then write some straight SQL to transform the data into another SQL database or the same part of the database.

You can access the SSIS object model from C# and build a package (or modify a template package)  programmatically and then execute it.  This might offer the best bang for your buck, but the SSIS object model is kind of deep.  The SSIS Team blog have [finally started putting up examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/samples-for-creating-ssis-packages-programmatically.aspx) (a year after I had to figure a lot of this out for myself)

There is always the upsizing wizard, and I'm sure there are some third party tools.